# Binding in mapping converter

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, ivalueconverter

I try to use MappingConverter (existed in our appication and worked nice) in this way:

```
<converters:MappingConverter x:Key="RewardTypeToSymbolConverter"
                             ElseMappingValue="BlaBla">
    <converters:MappingEntry FromValue="{x:Static loc:SomeEnum.Value}"
                             ToValue="{Binding SomeStringInViewModel}" />
</converters:MappingConverter>
```

I get no exceptions, but my TextBlock show nothing. Breakpoint within a converter shows that ToValue property is NULL (but SomeStringInViewModel isn't).

Do anybody have some idea how can I use binding like this within a converter? Or using binding in resource is impossible?

Comment: Please provide some code around `<converters:MappingConverter .../>`. How do you bind the converter to the `TextBlock`?

Comment: FromValue, ToValue, ElseMappingValue are dependency properties and it's type is object. Here is some information about MappingConverter (http://wpfconverters.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=User%20Documentation#MapConverter). I use it this way:

Comment: <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyEnum, Converter={StaticResource RewardTypeToSymbolConverter}" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converters are not in any tree, be it logical or visual. There should be no DataContext at all, if you want to do any kind of binding there you should specify a source (`RelativeSource` will of course not work) in addition to the path.

In any case, have a look at the output window of Visual Studio, the binding errors displayed there often help find the problem. Also see [this article on debugging bindings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx).

Comment: I specified a source of a binding and it worked nice. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Because Converters aren't in any tree, the DataBinding of the `ToValue` will not work.
Have look at Josh Smiths [DataContext-Bridge-Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachingVirtualBranches.aspx?msg=3400749).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your DataContext is incorrect

I would recommend using a tool like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/60745) to figure out what your DataContext is

Comment: The DataContext is Correct: other TextBlock that bounded same string not via converter displays correct data.

Comment: @eyjafjallajokull I think the DataContext for the Converter may be wrong since it is a Static converter.